# Fork, Parent and child process

Tags: c, linux

In C, is it possible to have the forked() process alive indefinitely even after the parent exits?

The idea of what I am trying to do is, Parent process forks a child, then exits, child keeps running in background until another process sends it a kill signal.

Comment: Isn't that how every daemon is implemented?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer. I'm quite new to C(5 months, by myself), and I learned about fork and wanted to try some things.

Comment: Daemons are processes that run in the background, not attached to any terminal. The standard way to start a daemon is precisely in the way you describe.

Comment: @KerrekSB: daemons don't run in the background. Background and foreground (process groups) only exist in relation to terminals, and since daemons don't have a controlling terminal, they run neither in the foreground nor in the background (of any terminal).

Comment: @ninjalj: Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to keep the child alive. The other responders are also correct; this is how a "daemon" or background process runs in a Linux environment.

Some call this the "fork off and die" approach. Here's a link describing how to do it:
http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Fork_off_and_die

Note that more than just fork()-ing is done. File descriptors are closed to keep the background process from tying up system resources, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Kerrek is right, this exactly the way how every daemon is implemented. So, your idea is perfect.

Comment: Thank you, quite new to this, but how would i achieve that? I tryed putting the child on an infinite loop, but it ended anyway. :S

Comment: Well, even that is a right way. Almost every daemon does some kind of infinite work, perhaps mainly sleeping and e.g. listening on sockets (httpd) or waiting for signals.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) library function which is very easy to use for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `daemon()` function call is not without limitations if you want to
write a well-behaved daemon. See *[On Starting Daemons](http://welz.org.za/notes/on-starting-daemons.html)*
for an explanation.

Briefly: A good daemon should only background when it is ready to field requests, but do its setup under its own PID and print startup errors